# Кафка и реляционная база?

Tags: apache-kafka

Пытаюсь спроектировать информационную систему с применением Кафки. Возникает вопрос, нужно ли использовать реляционную базу для хранения статических данных - таких как информация о пользователях и клиентах?
И например туже самую Mongodb - для хранения товаров и их свойства.
Или, ключевой вопрос, можно обойтись хранением всей этой информации в топиках Кафки?

Как правильон принять решение? Какие минусы и плюсы?

Comment: Хранить то можно все. А вот как вы искать будете ? kafka предназначена для потокового воспроизведения больших блоков информации, вы в ней просто не сможете найти клиента с id=123 и последнюю версию информации о нем не пересматривая весь массив данных

Comment: Почему нельзя - можно заюзать KSQLDB

Comment: kafka предназначена для потокового воспроизведения больших блоков информации - поясните пожалуйста?

Comment: Скажем у вас топик из одного раздела в 1 Гбайт. ksql что бы найти в нем одну запись надо этот 1 Гб с диска поднять и весь просканировать. он предназначен для построения аналиники на большом объеме данных за приемлемое для таких операций время, а не для работы с единичными мелкими строками